# SQL Select with Priority

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need to select top 1 most valid discount for a given FriendId.
I have the following tables:

**DiscountTable** - describes different discount types

```
DiscountId, Percent, Type,        Rank
1         , 20     , Friend,      2
2         , 10     , Overwrite,   1
```

Then I have another two tables (both list FriendIds)

**Friends**

```
101
102
103
```

**Overwrites**

```
101
105
```

I have to select top 1 most valid discount for a given FriendId. So for the above data this would be sample output

```
Id = 101 => gets "Overwrite" discount (higher rank)
Id = 102 => gets "Friend" discount (only in friends table)
Id = 103 => gets "Friend" discount (only in friends table)
Id = 105 => gets "Overwrite" discount
Id = 106 => gets NO discount as it does not exist in neither Friend and overwrite tables


INPUT => SINGLE friendId (int). 
OUTPUT => Single DISCOUNT Record (DiscountId, Percent, Type)
```

Overwrites and Friend tables are the same. They only hold list of Ids (single column)

Comment: Where would `106` come from then?  Are the structures of `Friends` and `Overwrites` actually identical, or just for purposes of your sample?

Comment: With as many points as you have around here you should know you need to post more information than this.

Comment: Can't you simply select top 1 [Columns] from [tables] order by ID?

Comment: Are friend and overwrite the only two potential discounts? Or might there be more added later?

Comment: For now only those two tables are used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having multiple tables of identical structure is usually bad practice, a single table with `ID` and `Type` would suffice, you could then use it in a `JOIN` to your `DiscountTable`:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT ID,[Type] = 'Friend' 
              FROM  Friends
              UNION  ALL
              SELECT ID,[Type] = 'Overwrite' 
              FROM  Overwrites
              )
SELECT TOP 1 a.[Type]
FROM cte a
JOIN DiscountTable DT
  ON a.[Type] = DT.[Type]
WHERE ID = '105'
ORDER BY [Rank]
```

Note, non-existent `ID` values will not return.

Comment: this works. Thank you!. If more "Overwrite" tables DO come I guess I could UNION that as well?

Comment: @shawnt00 Agreed, that's what I understood the OP to be looking for.  If the need was different I'd use `ROW_NUMBER()` and another cte to pull all ID's.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you all the FriendIds and the associate discount of the highest rank. It's an older hack that doesn't require using top or row numbering.

```
select
    elig.FriendId,
    min(Rank * 10000 + DiscountId) % 10000 as DiscountId
    min(Rank * 10000 + Percent) % 10000 as Percent,
from 
    DiscountTable as dt
    inner join (
        select FriendId, 'Friend' as Type from Friends union all
        select FriendId, 'Overwrite' from Overwrites
    ) as elig /* for eligible? */
        on elig.Type = dt.Type
group by
    elig.FriendId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table discounts (id int, percent1 int, type1 varchar(12), rank1 int)

insert into discounts
 values (1         , 20     , 'Friend',      2),

(2         , 10     , 'Overwrite',   1)


create table friends (friendid int)

insert into friends values (101),(102), (103)

create table overwrites (overwriteid int) 
insert into overwrites values (101),(105)

 select ids, isnull(percent1,0) as discount from (
select  case when   friendid IS null and overwriteid is null then 'no discount'
 when friendid is null and overwriteid is not null then 'overwrite'

      when friendid is not null and overwriteid is null then 'friend' 

      when friendid is not null and overwriteid is not  null then (select top 1 TYPE1 from discounts order by rank1 desc)
      else '' end category
      ,ids
  from tcase left outer join friends 
on tcase.ids = friends.friendid
left join overwrites
on tcase.ids = overwrites.overwriteid
 ) category1 left join discounts
 on category1.category=discounts.type1
```